# jQuery with Angular 4: InjectionToken vs TypeScript imports

Tags: jquery, angular

Provided I've installed jquery & its types:

```
npm i jquery
npm i @types/jquery
```

and ability to import it

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

now I have full:

- TypeScript support
- jQuery is automatically included in the bundle (I used Angular CLI)

So my question is: why should I bother use InjectionToken (previously OpaqueToken) to have another layer around jQuery?  I mean: what would be real benefits? Probably I could mock jQuery when unit testing, but in Angular apps I never actually did it and never saw it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testability is one of the benefits of DI and the most obvious reasons why it is a good habit to use both globals and imported libraries as Angular providers (even if jQuery is imported, it can still be a global). It's much easier to spy or stub a provider than imported module.

DI makes it easier to maintain several jQuery versions within same application with `jQuery.noConflict()`. This eliminates the problem If third-party modules rely on some jQuery version, and application units rely on another one.

DI provides some discretion for server side rendering. Even though it's possible to use jQuery in Node.js, this will require to provide `window` instance with DOM implementation. With DI it's possible to easily replace jQuery in application units with Node-friendly implementation like Cheerio or some stub that doesn't involve DOM.